# Disable disk encryption prompt remotely ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, encryption, disk

I need to restart my machine which I do not have physical access due to COVID. I enabled disk encryption on my Ubuntu when I installed it back when things were normal. Every-time I needed to restart the machine I was in the office to enter the password to decrypt the disk. I now work from home and I do not have the luxury to go the office any time soon. Because of Nvidia driver mismatch, I need to restart my machine for that problem to go away. As you might know, I will lose my machine due to the disk password prompt which holds the machine from completing the booting process.

Is there a way to **disable the disk encryption password prompt remotely**? I have full access from my SSH and I also have root permissions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and report hereb